# $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution. $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability. Does $(X_n, Y_n)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ in distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variable, convergence

As the title stated, $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution. $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ in probability. Does $(X_n, Y_n)$ converges to $(X,Y)$ in distribution?

If not, if we make the condition so that $Y_n$ converge to $Y$ almost surely, does $(X_n, Y_n)$ converge in distribution to $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Firstly, convergence in probability implies weak convergence. Then, component wise weak convergence doesn't imply the random vector would converge too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counterexample:  Let $X, Y \text{ i.i.d.} \sim N(0, 1)$, and let $(X_n, Y_n) \equiv (-Y, Y)$ for all $n$. It is easy to see that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, $Y_n$ converges to $Y$ almost surely.  But $X_n + Y_n = 0$ does not converge in distribution to $X + Y \sim N(0, 2)$, which implies that $(X_n, Y_n)$ couldn't converge to $(X, Y)$ in distribution (why?).

Comment: Regarding the "why?", I'm guessing that it's the contrapositive of the statement "if $(X_n,Y_n)$ converges in distribution to $(X,Y)$, then $X_n + Y_n$ converges to $X + Y$ in distribution". Is this correct?

Comment: @mhdadk Exactly.

Comment: Related relevant post on Math.SE (by Zhanxiong): [Does convergence in distribution of components imply convergence for the random vector too?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547883/1074816).

Answer (score 1):

While this is wrong in general as per [Zhanxiong](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/20519/zhanxiong)'s [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/611492/265966), it holds true if $Y$ is almost surely constant. I.e.

> If $X_n \overset{d}\to X$ and $Y_n \overset{p}\to c$, then $(X_n, Y_n)\overset{d}\to (X, c)$.

This is the key lemma for [Slutsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) which is then a simple corollary following from the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem).

#### Proof

(taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propB2)):

> ##### Lemma ("Pull along")
>
> If $X_n \overset{d}\to X$ and $|X_n - Y_n|\overset{p}\to 0$, then $Y_n \overset{d}\to X$.

By the lemma above, it is sufficient to prove

1. $(X_n, c) \overset{d}\to (X,c)$
2. $|(X_n, Y_n)-(X_n, c)|\overset{p}\to 0$

The second one follows immediately by $Y_n \overset{p}\to c$, the first one follows from the fact that $g:x\mapsto f(x,c)$ is a continuous function and thus by definition of convergence in distribution
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X_n, c)] = \mathbb{E}[g(X_n)] \to \mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f(X,c)].
$$

What remains to be shown is the "Pull along" lemma. In essence we want to apply a triangle inequality

$$
\Bigl|\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n)]-\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\Bigr| \le \Bigl|\mathbb{E}[f(Y_n)]-\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]\Bigr| + \underbrace{\Bigl|\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)]-\mathbb{E}[f(X)]\Bigr|}_{\to 0 \quad (X_n\overset{d}\to X)}
$$
Intuitively it is obvious that the first part should converge to zero as $X_n \overset{p}\to Y_n$ should imply $X_n \overset{d}\to Y_n$. But this is of course not formally correct. So we essentially restate the proof of $X_n\overset{p}\to X$ implies $X_n\overset{d}\to X$ manually.

By the portmanteau theorem it is sufficient to show convergence for bounded Lipschitz functions, so let $f$ be bounded by $M$ and $K$-Lipschitz. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left|\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y_n)\right] - \mathbb{E}\left [f(X_n) \right] \right| \\
&\leq \mathbb{E} \left [\left |f(Y_n) - f(X_n) \right | \right ]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ \left |f(Y_n) - f(X_n) \right |\mathbf{1}_{\left \{|Y_n-X_n|<\varepsilon \right \}} \right] + \mathbb{E}\left[ \left |f(Y_n) - f(X_n) \right |\mathbf{1}_{\left \{|Y_n-X_n|\geq\varepsilon \right \}} \right] \\
&\leq \mathbb{E}\left[K \left |Y_n - X_n \right |\mathbf{1}_{\left \{|Y_n-X_n|<\varepsilon \right \}}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[2M\mathbf{1}_{\left \{|Y_n-X_n|\geq\varepsilon \right \}}\right] \\
&\leq K \varepsilon \mathbb{P} \left (\left |Y_n-X_n \right |<\varepsilon\right) + 2M \mathbb{P} \left( \left |Y_n-X_n \right |\geq\varepsilon\right )\\
&\leq K \varepsilon + 2M \mathbb{P} \left (\left |Y_n-X_n \right |\geq\varepsilon \right )
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left|\mathbb{E}\left[f(Y_n)\right] - \mathbb{E}\left [f(X_n) \right] \right|
\le K \varepsilon
$$
and $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary. So the limit has to be zero.